# How to extract the value of the data-id attribute of the button control using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a button control on a web page as

```
<button class="btn btn-mini download-attachment pull-right width100px margin-bottom-1px" type="button" data-id="48156"><i class="icon-download"></i>&nbsp;Download</button>
```

I want to get the data-id associated with it. I am using selenium. Please suggest how can i fetch the data-id of this button control.

Comment: You can get the element by class name and then fetch the attribute `data-id`

Comment: You need to add a tag for the programming language that you want.

Answer (score 1):

To print the value of the *`data-id`* attribute you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *C#* and *XPath*:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[contains(@class, 'download-attachment')][.//i[@class='icon-download']]"))).GetAttribute("value"));
  ```
- Using *Java* and *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'download-attachment')][.//i[@class='icon-download']]"))).getAttribute("data-id"));
  ```
- Using *Python* and *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'download-attachment')][.//i[@class='icon-download']]"))).get_attribute("data-id"))
  ```
- **Note** : For [python](/questions/tagged/python) clients you have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```